# How to run single job for different URL/Environments in Jenkins?

Tags: ant, jenkins, soapui, build.xml

I am working on SOAP UI project for which I have done CI with Jenkins. I have created different jobs in Jenkins for each URL/environment but client want me to create a single job in which he can decide on which URL he wants to run the project. Please suggest me how to do so. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not aware about SOAP UI but are you planning for some drop-down list that would contain URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a parameterized job, with a dropdown list as the base URL of all the environments under test.